# How to get the value of variable using the value of textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`<input class="red" id="LR2"  type="text"  value="1" >`

```
<p id="demo"></p>  <br>
```

This is my **JS** code:

```
<script>

var price3 = 7;   <br>
var price4 = 8;   <br>

var selectValue = function RedAlert(data) {  <br>
if( $("#LR2").val() = 0) {  <br>
var price1 = 5;  <br>
}  <br>
else {  <br>
var price2 = 6; <br>
} <br>
}  <br>

var total = selectValue + price3 + price4; <br>
document.getElementById("LR2").innerHTML =  <br>
"The total is: " + total;  <br>
</script>  <br>
```

Comment: What kind of code it is with <br> inside js code, could you please fix the script

Comment: This is my [https://jsfiddle.net/renzf/ywzgpfbg/]

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
$("#LR2").val() = 0
```

should be :

```
$("#LR2").val() == 0
```

also not sure if the value isn't a string... maybe should cast to number like :

```
Number( $("#LR2").val() ) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var selectValue = 0;
 if( $("#LR2").val() == 0) { 
    selectValue = 5; 
 } 
 else { 
    selectValue = 6; 
 }
```